# How to remain text on searchview on toolbar when i change the fragment in viewpager?

Tags: android

Explanation:
            Hi developers, I am going to explain all the scenario over here.I have an one activity where i have put the viewpager and viewpager shows all the three fragment respectively. It namely such as FragmentA,FragmentB and FragmentC. I also have put the searchview on each and every fragment separately.Consider a situation when i am in FragmentA and added some text on the SearchView of FragmentA and swipe the screen from right to left it will show me FragmentB. Up until now everything working fine. When i go back to fragmentB to FragmenntA SearchView text cleaned in SearchView and list show according to the previous searchable item.Even it not refresh the RecyclerView items.

Here is the code of the FragmentA

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_refresh, menu);

        Log.e(TAG,"DONE");
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setVisible(false);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search Make");
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchView.setFocusable(true);
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();

        // listening to search query text change
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when query submitted
                makeAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when text is changed
                makeAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }
        });
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

In above code i declare searchView object globally.

Question:
        How can i remain the searchable text over the SearchView when i back from any fragment to FragmentA?
        How can i refresh the listview according tot he search text when i back from any fragment to FragmentA?

Please give me a reasonable solution for this question.

Comment: Consider taking code at activity level for search view and make interface to communicate between fragments for that searchview, you can also use **android architecture components** for sake of your code quality.

Comment: But i have make the adapter object in every Fragment and it's act accordingly.

Comment: so simply use one `SearchView`, shared by all your `Fragment`s

Comment: How can i identify in which fragment i am currently and how to manage it'search.Assume I am in FragmentC i have to search only FragmentC listView.

Comment: read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager) carefully

Comment: tRY REMOVING earchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

Comment: also make a null check in your searchview:   if (searchView != null && 
          !searchView.getQuery().toString().isEmpty())

Comment: do you need same data in all three fragment according to searchable text?

Comment: yes, I need to search data in all three fragment